# How to inject a jersey helper class with my non-bean object?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey-2.0

I am starting up a jersey server, and registering filters on it.

```
public static HttpServer startServer() {
        // create a resource config that scans for JAX-RS resources and providers
        // in com.example package
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig()
                .packages("com.resource_packages")
                .register(JacksonFeature.class)
                .register(
                        new AbstractBinder() {
                            @Override
                            protected void configure() {

                                bindFactory(new FooFactory()).to(Foo.class).in(Singleton.class);
                              }
                        })
                .register(ContainerRequestFilter.class)
                .register(ContainerResponseFilter.class);

        // create and start a new instance of grizzly http server
        // exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
    }
```

In my filter class i'm trying to inject an object using javax.Inject

```
class ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Inject    
    Foo foo;

}

class Foo {
    private A objectA;
    private B objectB;

    Foo(A objectA, B objectB) {
        this.objectA = objectA;
        this.objectB = objectB;
    }
}
```

I understand that Jersey uses hk2 for dependency injection, so how can I make Jersey's hk2 dependency injection aware of my non-resource, or jersey specific class?

Comment: The object "foo" is coming up as null because the @Inject is not having any effect on it.